# Comparing contents in the given tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I've two python class 'tuples' and and i want to compare contents on both of them and get only which is only in 'deactivated' tuple for eg.,

```
deactivated = ((34, 'abcd'), (250, 'def'), (350, 'xyz'))
schedules = ((34, 'abcd'), (250, 'def'))
to_deactivate = ()
```

in here, i want to push `(350, 'xyz')` which is not in schedules to another variable `to_deactivate`.

I've looked into some of the solutions online but most of them are just comparing whether the tuples are same or not. Please help me out on this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you familiar with list comprehension and membership checks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
deactivated = ((34, "abcd"), (250, "def"), (350, "xyz"))
schedules = ((34, "abcd"), (250, "def"))

to_deactivate = tuple(tpl for tpl in deactivated if tpl not in schedules)
print(to_deactivate)
```

Prints:

```
((350, 'xyz'),)
```

Comment: Conversion to a set would be useful here for larger inputs, so that membership tests are O(1) on average. I'd go even with set difference for readability purposes, if order is not important: `set(deactivated) - set(scheduled)`

Comment: @SUTerliakov As my timings (in my answer) show, even with that small inputs, and even if order is important (that is converting to set just for this operation, but keeping everything in tuples), it is still faster with sets. And, indeed, that advantage is more and more obvious as data size increases.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you those variables should be tuples?

Because tuples are immutable. In their essence, you are not supposed to add or remove things from them. It looks like those variables are intended to be collections to which you add or remove things. Which is not possible with tuples.

For example, sets, since you don't seem to bother about order, but do seem to be interested about what is or is not in them. That is what `sets` are for. Very quick to check whether something is in it or not (with the same easy `in` operator. But `in` is O(n) for lists or tuples, and is O(log(n)), and in practice even O(1) with sets).

So, that is just a remark, but I feel that those variables should have been sets.
In which case, answer to your question would simply have been

```py
to_deactivate =  deactivated - schedules
```

Even if you insist on keeping them as tuples, one compact answer is still to use sets

```py
to_deactivate=tuple(set(deactivated)-set(schedules))
```

Note that this is faster than the compound tuple solution. (1.38 μs vs 1.59 μs on my computer. And the timing difference grows when the size of the input tuples grows)

### Timings

Just to make my point about timing clear, here is how much times it takes to compute is with the "compound tuple" strategy (Andrej's answer)

[image]

Of course, curve fitting is not a complexity method evaluation, but, well, since instinct says that we can expect either O(n), O(nlog(n)) or O(n²) complexity, we can conclude that we are clearly on the O(n²) side here.

Where as with conversion to sets :
[image]

Which looks as a straight line as it can get.
So, clearly, on the O(n) side.

And, of course, put together, we have a match clearly in favor of sets.

[image]

And to reply to SUTerliakov's comment: not just for big values. Even at the very start, sets win. Just a zoom on previous graph.

[image]

And that is comparing set in their most defavorable usage: when we keep every thing in tuples, and then convert to set only for the operation. It would be even faster if variables were sets from the beginning. And in the question, there is really no indication that there is a reason from them not to be sets.

Answer (score -1):

You could use iteration to compare every element in one tuple to every element of the other tuple and get the the value of index for which there exist value only in the first tuple

```
deactivated = ((34, 'abcd'), (250, 'def'), (350, 'xyz'))
schedules = ((34, 'abcd'), (250, 'def'))
to_deactivate = ()
for i in range(len(deactivated)):
    if deactivated[i] not in schedules:
        to_deactivate += deactivated[i]
print(to_deactivate)
```

This should work fine.

Edit: Iterating only once.

Comment: But `to_deactivate` is a tuple. You can't `.append()` a tuple. In fact, you can't alter a tuple in any way.

Comment: sorry about that. instead you could just concatenate the tuple. I've edited my answer too

Comment: That still doesn't work. You are concatenating a tuple of tuples with a tuple. Besides, be aware that you build a new tuple at each step. Tuples are immutable. You can't modify them (for example add something to them). The only way is to build a brand new tuple. Which is what you are doing. Well, what you would be doing with correction `to_deactivate += (deactivated[i],)`.

Comment: With that correction, it would work. But would not be a good idea. Because this is the same as saying `to_deactivate = to_deactivate + (deactivated[i],)`. That is to rebuild a new tuple. For each new elements. So a cost of O(n²)